# How to load data in store using google drive file or dropbox file?

Tags: javascript, extjs, jsonp

I am new to ExtJS and now I need to load data in store using a json file saved at google drive or dropbox. Is it possible to implement this without use of any server side language.

I am using jsonp right now. This is my code

```
Ext.define('POC.store.nodeData',{
  extend:'Ext.data.Store',

  alias: 'store.node',
  model: 'POC.model.NodeModel',

  // defining storeId for accessing through store manager
  config:{
    storeId: 'nodes'
  },

  // defining proxy with configuration settings
  proxy: {
    type: 'jsonp',
    url:  'http://172.16.60.121:1841/fewNodes.json',
    reader: {
      type: 'json'
    },
   },
   // autoLoad enabled
   autoLoad: true,
});
```

Link of file is: [`https://www.dropbox.com/s/9wao2694lesss3h/fewNodes.json`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9wao2694lesss3h/fewNodes.json)